# What would be the easiest way to rows and columns to list of list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i currently have a simple list of lists which represents a chess board, how would i use rows and columns to represent a piece on the board?

```
Board= [ ['bR','bKn','bB','bQ','bK','bB','bKn','bR'],
       ['bP','bP','bP','bP','bP','bP',' bP',' bP'],
       ['_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ',' _ ',' _ '],
       ['_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ',' _ ',' _ '],
       ['_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ',' _ ',' _ '],
       ['_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ','_ ',' _ ',' _ '],
       ['wP','wP','wP','wP','wP','wP',' wP',' wP'],
       ['wR','wKn','wB','wQ','wK','wB','wKn','wR'] ]
```

for example:

```
   while True:
        if [][] in Board is == 'wP': #fix
```

what could i use that would search through the whole board to find "wP" instead of specific indexes?

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "add an x and y axis"? And how do you expect to address this without using indexes?

Comment: i meant rows and columns, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: perhaps update the question to show how you would like to use row and columns - it is not very clear at the moment

Comment: (About the edited question) What do you mean by "find" a string such as 'wP'? That would usually mean to find a row index and column index for a cell containing that string, but you say you want to avoid "specific indexes", so I do not yet understand what you want.

Comment: `Board[row][column] == 'wP'`?

Comment: It is still unclear, what is your question? Are you asking, how to iterate through list of lists? You want to know if this data structure is correct?

Comment: Do you just want to test, if "wP" is still on the board? Like `any(["wP" in i for i in Board])`?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty unclear. If you have the row and column you can do `Board[row][column] == 'wP'`. This would tell you if that cell equals that string. If you want to say "where is the first position that equals string X":

```
def find_first_cell(cell_val):
    for row_idx, row in enumerate(Board):
        for col_idx, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell == cell_val:
                return row_idx, col_idx
    return -1, -1  # or you could raise an exception
```

If you wanted to take advantage of builtin list operations you could also store your Board as a single list and use index math to calculate where something at `row` and `col` is in the single list. Then searching could be done with the builtin list methods like `.index` or `'wP' in Board`.